# Invoke Angularjs controller method from Angularjs view which related to another Angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to Angularjs, I have created simple web application that takes the details from user and display the details in the view. I am facing problem while invoking a method of  one controller from another angular view. Can anyone help me, Thanks.

#### home.html

```
  <div id="main">
  <div id="first">
  <form ng-controller="homeController as model" ng-submit="push();">
  <h1>Vehicle Form</h1>
  <h4>Please fill all entries.</h4>
  <br>
 <label>Model :</label>
 <input name="dname" placeholder="Enter Model" type="text" ng-model="model.user.model">
  <br>
 <label>Name :</label>
 <input name="demail" placeholder="Enter name" type="text" ng-model="model.user.name">
 <br>
 <label>Color :</label>
 <input name="demail" placeholder="Enter color" type="text" ng-model="model.user.color">
 <br>
 <label>Price :</label>
 <input name="demail" placeholder="Your Email" type="text"ng-   model="model.user.price">
  <br>
  <input name="dsubmit" type="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
 </div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <br>
 <h1>Vehicle Table </h1>
 <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-users" ng-controller="homeController">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <tr ng-repeat="vehicle in hello">

                    <td>{{vehicle.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{vehicle.model}}</td>
                    <td>{{vehicle.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{vehicle.color}}</td>
                    <td>{{vehicle.price}}</td>
          <td><a class="btn mini blue-stripe" ui-sref="about" ng-click="setValue(vehicle.id)">Edit</a></td>
          <td><a href="#" class="confirm-delete btn mini red-stripe" role="button">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

 </table>
```

#### home.js (controller file)

```
 var myapp = angular.module('demo').controller("homeController",    function($scope,myService){

 myService.async().then(function(d){
    $scope.hello=d.data;
 });

 var model=this;
    model.user={
            id:"",
           model:"",
           name:"",
          color:"",
          price:""
        };

     $scope.push = function(){
     myService.saveUser(model.user);
     model.user='';
     }

  });
```

#### about.html

```
<div id="main">
<div id="first">
    <form ng-controller="aboutController" ng-submit="addValue();">
        <h1>Vehicle Edit Form</h1>
        <br>
        <label>Id :</label>
        <input name="id" placeholder="Enter Id" type="text" ng-model="id" value="value.id">
        <br>
        <label>Model :</label>
        <input name="model" placeholder="Enter Model" type="text" ng-model="model" value="value.model">
        <br>
        <label>Name :</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Enter name" type="text" ng-model="name" value="value.name">
        <br>
        <label>Color :</label>
        <input name="color" placeholder="Enter color" type="text" ng-model="color" value="value.color">
        <br>
        <label>Price :</label>
        <input name="price" placeholder="Your Email" type="text" ng-model="price" value="value.price">
        <br>
        <input name="update" type="Update" value="Send">
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

#### about.js (second controller)

```
  angular.module('demo').controller("aboutController", function($scope, aboutService) {
  $scope.value;
  $scope.setValue = function() {
     aboutService.getVehicle().success(function (response) {
       $scope.value = studs.data;
     })
  };

$scope.addValue = function () {
  var stud = {
    id:"$scope.id",
    model:"$scope.model",
    name:"$scope.name",
    color:"$scope.color",
    price:"$scope.price"

  };
  aboutService.setVehicle(stud).
  success( function (){
    concole.log("hello");
  })
  };
 });
```

#### rest.js(module file)

```
 var myapp = angular
.module('demo', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'Views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
          })

        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'Views/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'Views/contact.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        });

});
```

#### homeService.js

```
myapp.factory('myService',function($http){
var myService={
  async : function(){
    var promise= $http.get('http://192.168.50.127:8080/SpringRestfulVehicleDemo2/vehicle/all').then(function(response){
     return response;
    });
    return promise;
   },
  saveUser : function(userArray){
$http.post('http://192.168.50.127:8080/SpringRestfulVehicleDemo2/vehicle/add ',userArray).success(

   function(userArray,status,headers,config){
  });
 }
};
 return myService;
});
```

#### aboutService.js (another service file)

```
myapp.factory('aboutService',function($http){
var aboutService={};
var   urlBase='http://192.168.50.127:8080/SpringRestfulVehicleDemo2/vehicle/';

 aboutService.getVehicle = function () {
 retun $http.get(urlBase+'/byId/:id');
};
 aboutService.setVehicle= function (){
 return $http.post(urlBase+'/update/:id');
}
return aboutService;
});
```

What I am doing is getting data from server and displaying data in a table. I want to edit the selected row in another view. I facing an issue when I click edit button in `home.html`. It should invoke `about.js` (controller) `setValue()` method.

Comment: how do both of these views relate to each other?  is there another HTML file that has both of these views?  you can use `$broadcast` or `$emit` if you ***really*** need to communicate between views, but you are describing a simple master/details view that shouldn't need that.

Comment: @claies: Yes, I have index.html that has both of these views. both controller belongs to one module.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need your controllers to communicate to each other. Communication can happen using any of the following methods

1. Use $emit + $on / $broadcast + $on
2. Make a service which contains that function and is injected to the controllers which want to communicate with each other.

In your case either you can move the **setValue** method to a **shared service** between the controllers using it or you can use method 1.

You already know how to make a service. For method 1 example is given below:

```
app.controller('One', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(){
           $scope.parentmethod();
        });

        $scope.parentmethod = function() {
            // task
        }
    }
]);
app.controller('two', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $scope.childmethod = function() {
            $rootScope.$emit("CallParentMethod", {});
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I followed the second method but It's not working. What I did is  I have created a set and get methods in service file, set method called by controller 1 and get method called by controller 2. but data is not coming to controller 2.